# Integrating Karate Tests with JIRA

Tags: karate

Can Karate API tests be integrated with JIRA. Here is the background on this question:
1. We follow BDD automation approach for Web/App tests. We have been using [jBehave](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1212628/jbehave-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview) for this and it's been quite successful.
2. For microservices tests, we have been using Karate as standalone and now there is a need to integrate these tests with JIRA like other type of tests. With the excellent features Karate provides for API tests, we don't want to miss out and hence want to find a way to integrate it with JIRA.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, be aware that [Karate is not BDD](https://hackernoon.com/yes-karate-is-not-true-bdd-698bf4a9be39) - so there may not be a need / benefit doing JIRA integration the way you are expecting.

Since Karate exports the Cucumber JSON report output, maybe you don't have to do anything. Refer this thread on discussions for 3rd party integration options: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/619 - it is something we expect the other tools to support or the community to build.

Answer (score 0):

> As we saw in the above example, where we are producing a Junit report with the result of the tests, we need to import those results to your Jira instance, this can be done by simply submitting automation results to Xray through the REST API, by using one of the available CI/CD plugins (e.g. for Jenkins) or using the Jira interface to do so.

https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Testing+APIs+using+Karate+DSL#TestingAPIsusingKarateDSL-API